# Django, view get list of dictionaries from request

Tags: jquery, python, django, dictionary

I have an AJAX request call (with JQuery) to my django view. It sends to view this kind of data:

```
{"cityId": 1, "products_with_priority": [{"id": 1, "priority": 1}, {"id": 2, "priority": 2}, {"id": 3, "priority": 3}, {"id": 4, "priority": 4}, {"id": 5, "priority": 5}]}
```

In my django view, I'm trying to get this list like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    city_id = request.POST.get('city_id')
    products_priorities = request.POST.getlist("products_with_priority")
```

Where `city_id` returns `1` and `products_with_priority` returns empty array.

How it is possible to receive array of dictionaries from request?

Comment: Try this: `request.POST.getlist("products_with_priority[]")`

Comment: How you are sending the data via jQuery, as `form` or `data`!

Comment: @SathishKumarVG As `data`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure your dataType is `json`, and stringify your array:

```
dataType: 'json',
data: {'cityId': 1, 'products_with_priority': JSON.stringify([{"id": 1, "priority": 1}, {"id": 2, "priority": 2}, {"id": 3, "priority": 3}, {"id": 4, "priority": 4}, {"id": 5, "priority": 5}])}
```

Then use the (standard Python library) `json`'s `loads()` method in your Django view:

```
products_priorities = json.loads(request.POST.get('products_with_priority'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the data to json string.

And receive it like

```
data = json.loads(request.POST)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
send your data in a json string to django view and then
Try

def my_view(request):
    data = OrderedDict()
    data = json.loads(request.POST)
    city_id = data['city_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

In AJAX request, make sure you include the header:

```
content-type: application/json
```

Then if you are using Python 3 as I do, in Django View:

```
def my_view(request):
    received_json = json.loads(request.read().decode('utf-8'))
    products_priority = received_json['products_with_priority']
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are sending `POST` data as `jQuery (raw) data`, then you can access it via `body` as a `string`. From which you can load it as `JSON`. Hope the below example helps you.

```
def my_view(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    city_id = data.get('cityId')
    products_priorities = data.get("products_with_priority")
```

Comment: request.body is not testable via django Client() class.